# Sticky menu, stop parameter wont work

Tags: jquery, wordpress, menu, sticky

I can't seem to get rid of a small detail.

I have a moving sticky menu (for example: http://digitalgrid.cl/k/biontransit/que-es-bion-transit/), which mostly works, but I can't get it to stop where I want it to.

The green line in the footer is where the menu should stop moving, but no matter what I do, it keeps going a little bit further down. I am using id=stop to mark where the stopper should be, but no matter where I put it, it doesnt stay at the green line (or wherever).

The part that I want to move is wrapped in css class "sticky", using jQuery to make it move and stop:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $(".sticky").sticky({
            topSpacing: 8,
            zIndex:2,
            stopper: "#stop"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Edit: well, I ended up adding another div around the moving parts and gave it a 100px bottom padding and it stops right now, but I'd still like to know why its 100px off :\

Comment: Instead of an id, try adding a class to the stopper element called stopper. Idea: `'stopper' : '.stopper'` No promises...

Comment: Doesnt seem to make a difference :\